# What do you call a prior on the Sobolev norm of a function?

Tags: stochastic-processes, prior

I'm looking for other names for priors of the form
$$
-\log(p(f)) \propto \int \frac {\|f(x)\|^2 + \|f'(x)\|^2 } 2 dx
$$
that is, a $\chi^2$ prior on the [Sobolev norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) of a function.

I think this is some sort of [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process), but I don't know how to show a relationship.